# App uploaded to google play but in pending review

Tags: android

I did upload an app to google play and it's been 3 days and it's still in pending review, how to get it approved?
Also, I uploaded an extension to chrome web store and it is in pending as well?
Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to Google themselves, from a general search of the question:

> Usually, it takes up to 2 days. Google says the review process could take up to 7 days or even longer. Once the app is reviewed, you'll receive a notification on Google Console Dashboard.

They are most likely backed up with reviewing people's applications before the yare allowed be to published.

If further assistance is needed, you can [reference their FAQs about it here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en&visit_id=637645354661647013-2644989451&rd=1)

Comment: I got this reply: How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Issue with your app
Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Webviews and Affiliate Spam policy.
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):
In-app experience:
HTTP requests:

Answer (score 1):

The initial APK you upload on Google Play will take more time than usual.

Again it depends on app size and complexity. The maximum time I have faced recently for one of my client's app is 8 "working" days. I suggest waiting for few more days.

Also, if [Managed Publishing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en) is Enabled on your account, you have to keep an eye on the **Publishing overview** tab to check the status of recent changes.

You have to manually approve the updates to go live if you are using **Managed Publishing**.

[image: Publishing Overview screen of Notification History Log]